# 403 Forbidden when accessing image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am getting 403 Fobidden error when trying to access directly from URL.

Here is my blog page url : http://www.modestmoney.com/peer-lending-returns-still-sizzling/

Images are displaying in post details page correctly but when i am trying to access the same image directly from url like below then it will giving me 403 Forbidden Error
http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg

When we right click on the post image and open image in new tab then it will be opened as below:

http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg?1a2ec8

So the images are accessible when we add `?1a2ec8` parameter but i dont know why its added automatically?

My upload directory has `0755` permission and all the images have `0644` permission. I have installed W3TC plugin.

Can you please advise me on this what should i do to access images directly from the url like: http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Peer-Lending1.jpg

Comment: does it work if you disable W3TC?

Comment: Can you make sure there is no server directive that would disallow hotlinking?

Comment: @Karthik I have not tried to disable W3TC because i am scared if my all the settings will be reset which i have done in W3TC.

Comment: @LeonardoBaptistaLopes there is no server directive that disallow  hotlinking

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.modestmoney.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/
Then click on the Peer-Lending1.jpg file listing.